# Blocking traffic direct to backend server haproxy

Tags: linux, php, routing, web-server, haproxy

I have the following problem. I have set up a reverse proxy using HaProxy. Now there are still users accessing the Backend IP Direct. And thus (unprotected) accessing the infrastructure without the reverse proxy.

I would like the traffic to be redirected automatically when they access the Backend IP. Unfortunately I have a problem.

If I set up a redirection on the backend to the reverse proxy with php then they land on the reverse proxy and it redirects to the backend originally. Now a loop is created which leads the backend to reverse and the reverse to the backend. How can I force the user to access the reverse proxy url ?

Comment: Tell the backend to redirect if the source isn't HAProxy. You redirect users, you don't redirect HAProxy, no loop.

Comment: @Ginnungagap Can you tell me how i can make it ?

Comment: That's your backend so no, basically just check the origin IP and redirect if it isn't HAProxy's.